# Google Maps API example not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to using the Google Maps API, I'm using some example code of off Googles documentation that doesn't work and I was wondering if anyone can help me solve why it wouldn't work for me? Here is the code itself:`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true" ></script>`

```
    <script>
  var directionDisplay;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var map;

  function initialize() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom:7,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: chicago
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  }

  function calcRoute() {
    var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
    var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
    var request = {
        origin:start,
        destination:end,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

Here is the HTML:

```
`  <body onload="initialize()">
<div>
<b>Start: </b>
<select id="start" onchange="calcRoute();">
  <option value="chicago, il">Chicago</option>
  <option value="st louis, mo">St Louis</option>
  <option value="joplin, mo">Joplin, MO</option>
  <option value="oklahoma city, ok">Oklahoma City</option>
  <option value="amarillo, tx">Amarillo</option>
  <option value="gallup, nm">Gallup, NM</option>
  <option value="flagstaff, az">Flagstaff, AZ</option>
  <option value="winona, az">Winona</option>
  <option value="kingman, az">Kingman</option>
  <option value="barstow, ca">Barstow</option>
  <option value="san bernardino, ca">San Bernardino</option>
  <option value="los angeles, ca">Los Angeles</option>
</select>
<b>End: </b>
<select id="end" onchange="calcRoute();">
  <option value="chicago, il">Chicago</option>
  <option value="st louis, mo">St Louis</option>
  <option value="joplin, mo">Joplin, MO</option>
  <option value="oklahoma city, ok">Oklahoma City</option>
  <option value="amarillo, tx">Amarillo</option>
  <option value="gallup, nm">Gallup, NM</option>
  <option value="flagstaff, az">Flagstaff, AZ</option>
  <option value="winona, az">Winona</option>
  <option value="kingman, az">Kingman</option>
  <option value="barstow, ca">Barstow</option>
  <option value="san bernardino, ca">San Bernardino</option>
  <option value="los angeles, ca">Los Angeles</option>
</select>
</div>`
```

Comment: To my understanding u need google id/key to be able to do google map. Do you have one?

Comment: I have at the very top of the script?

Comment: When I add my API key in I always get this message:
Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. The key provided is not a valid Google API Key or it is not authorised for the Google Maps JavaScript API v3 on this site. If you are the owner of this application, you can learn about obtaining a valid key here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key

Comment: well there you go. the site you're using it hasn't been set in the api settings.

Comment: Im running it off a file in my desktop?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have elements to get the `start` and `end` values? This code works when I route from joliet to naperville:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<style>
#map-canvas {height:500px;width:500px;}
</style>
</head>

<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<div>
<b>Start: </b>
<select id="start" onchange="calcRoute();">
  <option value="chicago, il">Chicago</option>
  <option value="st louis, mo">St Louis</option>
  <option value="joplin, mo">Joplin, MO</option>
  <option value="oklahoma city, ok">Oklahoma City</option>
  <option value="amarillo, tx">Amarillo</option>
  <option value="gallup, nm">Gallup, NM</option>
  <option value="flagstaff, az">Flagstaff, AZ</option>
  <option value="winona, az">Winona</option>
  <option value="kingman, az">Kingman</option>
  <option value="barstow, ca">Barstow</option>
  <option value="san bernardino, ca">San Bernardino</option>
  <option value="los angeles, ca">Los Angeles</option>
</select>
<b>End: </b>
<select id="end" onchange="calcRoute();">
  <option value="chicago, il">Chicago</option>
  <option value="st louis, mo">St Louis</option>
  <option value="joplin, mo">Joplin, MO</option>
  <option value="oklahoma city, ok">Oklahoma City</option>
  <option value="amarillo, tx">Amarillo</option>
  <option value="gallup, nm">Gallup, NM</option>
  <option value="flagstaff, az">Flagstaff, AZ</option>
  <option value="winona, az">Winona</option>
  <option value="kingman, az">Kingman</option>
  <option value="barstow, ca">Barstow</option>
  <option value="san bernardino, ca">San Bernardino</option>
  <option value="los angeles, ca">Los Angeles</option>
</select>
</div>`
        <script>
  var directionDisplay;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var map;

  function initialize() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom:7,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: chicago
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  }

  function calcRoute() {
    var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
    var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
    var request = {
        origin:start,
        destination:end,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what DOESN'T work in yours? Do you not get a map? not get a route? Do you have some way to actually run the `calcRoute` function (like the "go" button I have here)?

Comment: Sorry I probably should have said, I don't get a map or anything

Comment: Ahhh I have a map now I have added the CSS! but the map it self doesn't function as expcted to?

Comment: I still get this error:Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. The key provided is not a valid Google API Key or it is not authorised for the Google Maps JavaScript API v3 on this site. If you are the owner of this application, you can learn about obtaining a valid key here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key

Aswell, but I've generated new keys from my Google account and still get the same message.

Comment: in what way? I just edited my code above to use your selectors and it works fine for me

Comment: It doesn't present a route or anything, the dropdowns may aswell not be there?

Comment: so take out the key...my sample doesn't have one

Comment: Yeah I don't get the error without the key now, just need to get it to show a route?

Comment: Latest version of Firefox, yeah it works with producing a map etc, but it doesn't present directions on the map

Comment: I've just checked it and it's working properly!! Thank you very much :)

Comment: The noted difference and what seems to be the real fix is that the Google examples don't provide a size for the "map-canvas" div, so they  wind up being invisible.  The thing that makes it work is the style element providing the size.  Even their documentation states you must set this size, but their example of inline style on the div tag for the size doesn't work for me, only the way shown in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

There also appears to be an errant ` after ending div of the end combobox. Causes no harm but doesn't belong.

Answer (score 0):

The initialize() function needs to be called. It can be in the `<body>` tag like this:

```
<body onload="initialize();">
```

Comment: And do you also have an element with id=map-canvas inside the page, where the map is to be displayed?

Comment: Yeah I do it's below all my HTML